# Android - Black BG color issue in canvas masking

Tags: android, canvas, masking

I an creating an android application in which i am going to crop a bitmap image using path in canvas.

I am able to cut the bitmap using path but it leaves black background on the remaining portion of the bitmap.

Below is my code to cut a bitmap with path and mask in canvas.

```
public Bitmap cropBitmap(Path path){

    Bitmap maskImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas maskCanvas = new Canvas(maskImage);

    maskCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    Paint pathPaint = new Paint();
    pathPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    pathPaint.setXfermode(null);
    pathPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    pathPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    maskCanvas.drawPath(path,pathPaint);


    Bitmap resultImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(resultImg);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    mCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(maskImage, 0, 0, paint);
    return resultImg;
}
```

and below is the input image with path.

[image]

and below is the result which i am getting right now.

[image]

I want to remove that black background portion.
that black portion should be transparent.
Is there any way i can remove that black portion and make it transparent?

Comment: Try using `paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER));`

Comment: Hey, @AjilO. i tried paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER)); but it's not working. it draws both image and path.

Comment: I assumed that what you meant was the black area should be transparent and hence should show the original image underneath? Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @AjilO. Yes, i want that black portion to be transparent and show original image underneath. Do you have any other idea how to get that done?